# Reading in data from file using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a data file with tons of data like:

```
{"Passenger Quarters",27.`,"Cardassian","not injured"},{"Passenger Quarters",9.`,"Cardassian","injured"},{"Passenger Quarters",32.`,"Romulan","not injured"},{"Bridge","Unknown","Romulan","not injured"}
```

I want to read in the data and save it in a list. I am having trouble getting the exact right code to exact the data between the { }. I don't want the quotes and the ` after the numbers. Also, data is not separated by line so how do I tell re.search where to begin looking for the next set of data?

Comment: Does that odd ` mean something? How did it get there? Can it be prevented in the first place so you don't have to deal with it now? Except for that odd thing, your file could be parsed easily and properly. And what are "tons of data"? More than a gigabyte?

Comment: Sorry by tons I just meant that that is not all the data. The ` is just there, it was in the data file I received and I don't think it means anything.

Comment: I managed to extract the first set of data in the { } but now how do I get it to go to the next set of data ?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, you can break this data into chunks by splitting it on the string `},{`:

```
chunks = data.split('},{')
chunks[0] = chunks[0][1:]      # first chunk started with '{'
chunks[-1] = chunks[-1][:-1]   # last chunk ended with '}'
```

Now you have chunks like

```
"Passenger Quarters",27.`,"Cardassian","not injured"
```

and you can apply a regular expression to them.

Comment: `chunks = data[1:-1].split('},{')`. Though that will obviously have problems if there is whitespace somewhere between the two braces.

Answer (score 0):

The following will produce a list of lists, where each list is an individual record.

```
import re

data = '{"Passenger Quarters",27.`,"Cardassian","not injured"},{"Passenger Quarters",9.`,"Cardassian","injured"},{"Pssenger Quarters",32.`,"Romulan","not injured"},{"Bridge","Unknown","Romulan","not injured"}'

# remove characters we don't want and split into individual fields
badchars = ['{','}','`','.','"']
newdata = data.translate(None, ''.join(badchars))
fields = newdata.split(',')

# Assemble groups of 4 fields into separate lists and  append
# to the parent list.  Obvious weakness here is if there are
# records that contain something other than 4 fields
records = []
myrecord = []
recordcount = 1
for field in fields:
    myrecord.append(field)
    recordcount = recordcount + 1
    if (recordcount > 4):
        records.append(myrecord)
        myrecord = []
        recordcount = 1

for record in records:
    print record
```

Output:

```
['Passenger Quarters', '27', 'Cardassian', 'not injured']
['Passenger Quarters', '9', 'Cardassian', 'injured']
['Pssenger Quarters', '32', 'Romulan', 'not injured']
['Bridge', 'Unknown', 'Romulan', 'not injured']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in two passes. One to get the list of items and one to get the contents of each item:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

data = '{"Passenger Quarters",27.`,"Cardassian","not injured"},{"Passenger Quarters",9.`,"Cardassian","injured"},{"Passenger Quarters",32.`,"Romulan","not injured"},{"Bridge","Unknown","Romulan","not injured"}'

# This splits up the data into items where each item is the
# contents inside a pair of braces
item_pattern = re.compile("{([^}]+)}")

# This plits up each item into it's parts. Either matching a string
# inside quotation marks or a number followed by some garbage
contents_pattern = re.compile('(?:"([^"]+)"|([0-9]+)[^,]+),?')

rows = []
for item in item_pattern.findall(data):
    row = []
    for content in contents_pattern.findall(item):
        if content[1]: # Number matched, treat it as one
            row.append(int(content[1]))
        else: # Number not matched, use the string (even if empty)
            row.append(content[0])
    rows.append(row)

pprint(rows)
```